Is there any other function than $log$ for which $f(ab) = f(a)+f(b)$ and $f$ is monotonic?
Is there any other function than $log_{x}$ for which $f(ab) = f(a)+f(b)$ and $f$ is monotonic?
If the answer to this question is yes, how can I find such functions?

There are the obvious other functions: logarithms to different bases.

Fixed the question. So logarithms to other bases excluded.

The constant function $0$

See this question.  To connect your function to Cauchy's, let $F(x)=f\circ \exp$.

Not if we assume that $f$ is differentiable and defined on $\mathbb R_{>0}$ (which is where $\log$ is defined), since then
$$ y \, f'(xy) = \frac{\text {d}}{\text {d} x} f(xy) = \frac{\text {d}}{\text {d} x} (f(x) + f(y)) = f'(x).$$
Setting $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and $f'(1)=a$,
$$ \frac{f'(1)}{x} = \frac{a}{x} = f'(x),$$
we integrate to get
$$f(x) = f(1) +\int_1^x \frac{a}{x'} \text {d} x' = f(1) + a \log (x),$$
and since $f(1) = f(1 \cdot1) = f(1)+f(1)$, we necessarily have $f(1)=0$. Thus, all the differentiable solutions to $f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)$ are of the form $a \log (x)$.

We begin with the provided functional equation:
$$\mathcal {f} \left( x y \right) = \mathcal {f} \left( x \right) + \mathcal {f} \left( y \right).$$
Rewrite the equation:
$$\mathcal {f} \left( x y \right) - \mathcal {f} \left( x \right) = \mathcal {f} \left( y \right).$$
See
$$\frac {\mathcal {f} \left( x y \right) - \mathcal {f} \left( x \right)}{x y - x} = \frac {1}{x} \cdot \frac {\mathcal {f} \left( y \right) - 0}{y - 1}.$$
Return for now to the original equation. Letting $x = y = 1$, we see $\mathcal {f} \left( 1 \right) = 0$.
Using this result, we continue and write
$$\frac {\mathcal {f} \left( x y \right) - \mathcal {f} \left( x \right)}{x y - x} = \frac {1}{x} \cdot \frac {\mathcal {f} \left( y \right) - \mathcal {f} \left( 1 \right)}{y - 1}.$$
Let $y \to 1$. Assuming differentiability, by definition,
$$\mathcal {f}' \left( x \right) = \frac {1}{x} \cdot \mathcal {f}' \left( 1 \right),$$
so
$$\mathcal {f} \left( x \right) = \mathcal {f}' \left( 1 \right) \ln \left( x \right).$$
In summary, assuming differentiability, then $\mathcal {f} \left( x \right) = a \ln \left( x \right)$ for all $a \in \mathbb {R}$. A special case is when $a = 0$. Then we have a zero function, which is trivial.

It's easy to see that $f(1)=0$, as $f(1 \cdot 1) = f(1) + f(1)$ :-)
Next thing to do, is choose another value.
Normally you take a value for $x$ and set the function value, but here we do it the other way around: for which $k$ is $f(k) = 1$?
You'll easily see that $f(x)= \log_k(x)$, proving that indeed logarithmic functions (or the constant zero function) are the only solutions.
